# How can I share code between AWS Lambda Layers?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I understand that you can share code among AWS Lambda functions when those functions use the same layer.

However, I want to reuse code among Lambda Layers.
Can I just reference the `/opt/nodejs/` folder inside my layer code in order to access another layer code hoping that both layers are being used by the same Lambda function?

E.g.

`layer1 --> /myFile1.ts`

`layer2 --> /myFile2.ts`

`myFunction` uses both `layer1` and `layer2`.

Can I do the following in my `/myFile1.ts` in order to use the `/myFile2.ts` code?

`import * as _ from 'opt/nodejs/layer2/myFile2.ts'`

Comment: Yes, you can add multiple layers to a function.

Comment: I would recommend to share code at build time, not at runtime. If you use a tool like `esbuild` you can build your Lambda from multiple shared libraries during build time, drastically simplifying your runtime setup.